# Decoding input data from transaction

Tags: transactions, decoding

I'm struggling with decoding the input data from transaction, have tried already everything that I found in similar topics here but all I can retrieve is:

```
{
  "method": null,
  "types": [],
  "inputs": [],
  "names": []
}
```

Transaction ID is 0x4e12c7c79be4b6f33ed271db399a354fd8016952c83df186985a7ff1103f2187.

That's how I try to do it:

1. Go to https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4e12c7c79be4b6f33ed271db399a354fd8016952c83df186985a7ff1103f2187 and copy the contents of "Input Data" field - this is what I need to decode.
2. "Interacted With (To)" field leads me to contract ID 0x9757F2d2b135150BBeb65308D4a91804107cd8D6 which is proxy, so I go to "Contract" tab, then "Read as Proxy" and there it points me to another contract 0xe441aefa11e775803dd47f5e949886b71a4b312d which seems to be a final exchange contract.
3. Open the final contract's page https://etherscan.io/address/0xe441aefa11e775803dd47f5e949886b71a4b312d#code, scroll to the bottom and copy the contents of "Contract ABI" field.
4. Open https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/, paste field values retrieved on previous steps ("ABI" & "Input Data") and then I receive the json I posted above as the result of decoding.

When trying to use another online tool or do it through the code (tried "ethereum-input-data-decoder" node library), I got the similar result. Also, tried to do it over the ABI of proxy contract itself (without going to the underlying proxied contract) - result is similar.

I would be very happy if someone code point me at the place where I'm doing something wrong. Thanks!

Here's my [screen recording](https://capture.dropbox.com/l9mVhOKRanl2ZO7b?src=ss) showing how I'm trying to do it.

Comment: I think the problem is in the decoders not supporting the abi.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give more information on it? Are there different ABI versions? Did not found anything about it in google. It's looking weird since many different tools & libs are giving similar result while they are looking working with ABI functionality out of the box, and there's nothing said about supporting or not supporting the abi.

Comment: With solc 0.8 *ABI coder v2 is activated by default.* https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/080-breaking-changes.html. I don't remember exactly but I think the v2 supports array of structs.

Comment: Im having same issue, did you find a solution ?